# Not able to insert data to mysql via servlet

Tags: android, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert data to a mysql table using the below methods but am not able to do so. Any idea on where I may be going wrong?

Method 1: Using HTTPClient to directly access the URL. Below is the code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://<lclhst>/GnPServlet/GetNpostServlet/?    account=1&password=123");
HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Method 2: Using URL connection to directly access the URL. Below is the code:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://<lclhst>/GnPServlet/GetNpostServlet/?    account=1&password=123");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
    conn.connect();
```

Method 3: Using Arraylist to pass values.

When i run the URL from the browser i get the success message "Inserted" and the data is inserted into the DB. But the same when tried through the app does not insert data. Below is the servlet code:

```
private String accountLookup(String acct, String pwd)
{
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
StringBuffer msgb = new StringBuffer("");

try
{
  // These will vary depending on your server/database      
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbone?user=root&password=root");

  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

  stmt.executeUpdate("insert into accttbl(address, description, time) values ('test 07-jul',ok,12:12)");
  return "Inserted";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return e.toString();
}
}
```

The below code inserts data but it opens the browser which I dont want. Also the data insertion is not always successful.

```
 String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/GnPServlet/GetNpostServlet";
                     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                     i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                     startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are encountering? Are there any exception stack traces? Can you post the code snippet for the MySQL persistence logic?

Comment: The issue im facing is when I run the URL in method 1 via a browser or J2ME app it connects to the servlet and data is inserted but same does not happen with the app. No exception but data is not getting inserted. I think there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Looks like you're sending a `POST` when the servlet expects a `GET` (which is what the browser would send if you just paste the URL into the URL bar)

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

...is most likely what you want since your parameters are encoded in the URL.

Also, are you sure that the spaces in your URL before account should be there?

Comment: Sorry the spaces are not there in the URL. I changed the code to conn.setRequestMethod("GET") but it still has not inserted data. Is there anything else I need to setup e.g. Port no.?

Comment: Just checked the servlet URL by running it on my emulators browser. It gives the HTTP Status 404 "Status report" page with description "Requested resource is not available". The same URL connects to the servlet on the m/c browser. Have changed localhost to 10.0.2.2 but it still does not seem to connect to the servlet.

Comment: @SidM Is 10.0.2.2 the IP of the machine running the servlet? I assume the servlet is not running on the phone...?

Comment: The machine is the same for both the Servlet and App. I am using 10.0.2.2 in the android code. I have not tried the servlet on an actual phone device as the machine IP is not public. On the emulator browser I get the 404 message stated above. On a normal browser it successfully connects and inserts the test data.

Comment: @SidM The emulator has its own IP, so localhost would connect to the emulator itself.

Comment: I am using 10.0.2.2 to access the machine running the servlet (which happens to be the same machine which is running the app). How can I confirm if its accessing the machine and not the emulator?

Comment: @ Joachim I am able to access the servlet via emulator browser by removing the parameter part of the URL e.g. http://10.0.2.2:8080/GnPServlet/GetNpostServlet/ but the same does not work when using HTTpClient or HttpURL connection in android code.

Comment: Any help on how I can access the servlet via the android app?